# How to load second selectOneMenu on change of first selectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf

I have 2 `<h:selectOneMenu>` components and one of them depends of the selection of the other. When you select one value of the first menu component, then the second changes with the event of `onchange="submit()"` and `valueChangeListener="#{Usuario.cmbDatos_action}"` of the first menu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="cmbCombo" binding="#{Usuario.cmbDatos}" value="#{Usuario.id}" 
    onchange="submit()" valueChangeListener="#{Usuario.cmbDatos_action}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{beanCombos.datos}"></f:selectItems>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

It is like Countries and Cities of the selected Country. The first menu is loaded as follows:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class BeanCombos {

    private List<SelectItem> Datos;

    public BeanCombos() {
        try {
            clsConexion objConexion = new clsConexion();
            String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios";            
            objConexion.ResultSetSQL = objConexion.EjecutarConsulta(strSQL);
            Datos = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();

            while (objConexion.ResultSetSQL.next()) {
                Usuario objUsuario = new Usuario();                
                objUsuario.setId(String.valueOf(objConexion.ResultSetSQL.getInt("Codigo")));
                objUsuario.setNombre(objConexion.ResultSetSQL.getString("Nombres").toUpperCase());
                Datos.add(new SelectItem(objUsuario.getId(), objUsuario.getNombre()));
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            String strError = ex.getMessage().toString();            
        }
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getDatos() {
        return Datos;
    }
}
```

But when I select one value of the first menu I don't know how load the next menu. I've tried it as follows:

```
public String cmbDatos_action() {
    try {
        int intValor = Integer.parseInt(cmbDatos.getValue().toString());
    } catch(Exception ex) {

    }

    return null;
}
```

In what part of method `cmbDatos_action()` can I put the code to load the second menu?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `valueChangeListener` should refer a method taking `ValueChangeEvent` argument and returning `void`.

```
public void cmbDatos_action(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

But you will run into trouble with regard to validation because you're basically submitting the *entire* form with `onchange="submit()"`. You'd need to add `immediate="true"` to the first menu component as well. See also [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/10/populate-child-menus.html) for a detailed explanation with concrete examples.

As you seem to be already using JSF 2.x, I recommend to forget this JSF 1.x based workaround and just go straight with the JSF 2.x `<f:ajax>` approach which is so much simpler to program.

Here's a kickoff example, based on "Countries" and "Cities" example:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.country}" converter="countryConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.countries}" var="country" itemValue="#{country}" itemLabel="#{country.name}" />
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.changeCountry}" render="cities" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<h:selectOneMenu id="cities" value="#{bean.city}" converter="cityConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.cities}" var="city" itemValue="#{city}" itemLabel="#{city.name}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

with for example

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class Bean {

    private List<Country> countries;
    private Country country;
    private List<City> cities;
    private City city;

    @EJB
    private DataService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        countries = service.getCountries();
    }

    public void changeCountry() {
        cities = service.getCities(country);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for completeness.